# How is Hunter adopted?

Tags: plot-explanation, paranormal-activity

In Paranormal Activity 3 (maybe it was PA 2?) Katie kidnaps Hunter when he was a baby. In Paranormal Activity 4 we find out that Wyatt is actually Hunter. How is this so? If Katie took him, why did she give him up only to come back after him? Is there a back story to explain this?

Further more, who is Robby? Was he just there to help prepare Wyatt to convert back into Hunter and "be with his family"?

Comment: I think this question required franchise tag rather then PA1 tag.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Still the tag `movie-franchise` is a bit overly broad (it's not that much better than `movie`, which I recently had to clear up). The tag `paranormal-activity` could very well stand for the entire franchise (though it's a bit unlucky the tag description doesn't account for that). It's not about the particulars of a movie franchise, but a `plot-explanation` which just happens to span multiple sequels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that Hunter's adoption was handled as a private affair using an attorney affiliated with the cult which is the behind scenes agent in the film series. This explains why no one seems to have interfered with his adoption by the family. the film series at this juncture has not made it clear as to the details of the Hunter/Katie scenario between when she kidnapped him and when his adoptive family is murdered.

It can be assumed that Katie placed Hunter up for adoption to make it difficult to locate both of them after the authorities found her sister's family murdered. She then comes to retrieve Hunter at a time when it is appropriate to do so and undertake additional sacrifices to the demonic entity worshiped by the cult.